# Insert transaction from demo does not work for me (docker kartoza)

Tags: insert, docker, geoserver, web-feature-service

I'm new to geoserver and I'm trying to understand the basics. So expect (I do) that I missed an obvious detail :-/.

I have a problem with the Insert Transaction request in the Demos available in the geoserver web interface. Simply, it does not show anything on the preview (tasmania_roads), as I expect. Instead, the Update demo works ok. The following is how to reproduce.

I have installed geoserver+postgis from kartoza on dockerhub on my linux workstation.

https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/

and it works ok with:

```
$ docker pull kartoza/postgis
$ docker pull kartoza/geoserver  
$ docker run --name "postgis" -d -t kartoza/postgis
$ docker run --name "geoserver" --link postgis:postgis -p 8080:8080 -d -t kartoza/geoserver`
```

The geoserver web interface is on 172.17.0.3:8080, and the servers are clean (no admin access on geoserver and postgis).

Now I cut the code of the demo (link Demos on the left of the geoserver web interface and select request "WFS_transactionInsert.xml") and copy it in a file (DemoInsert). I modify the IP of the geoserver and this is the result:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/topp http://172.17.0.3:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=topp:tasmania_roads">
 <wfs:Insert>
   <topp:tasmania_roads>
     <topp:the_geom>
      <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
         <gml:lineStringMember>
           <gml:LineString>
             <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
             </gml:coordinates>
           </gml:LineString>
         </gml:lineStringMember>
       </gml:MultiLineString>
     </topp:the_geom>
     <topp:TYPE>alley</topp:TYPE>
   </topp:tasmania_roads>
 </wfs:Insert>
```

Finally I POST the query to the geoserver:

```
curl -X POST -d @DemoInsert -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://172.17.0.3:8080/geoserver/wfs
```

and the reply is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse version="1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://172.17.0.3:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">
<wfs:InsertResult>
  <ogc:FeatureId fid="new0"/>
</wfs:InsertResult> 
<wfs:TransactionResult> 
  <wfs:Status> 
    <wfs:SUCCESS/> 
  </wfs:Status> 
</wfs:TransactionResult>
</wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse>
```

(here I have added some newlines).

But nothing happens on the map that I see in Data, Layer Preview in the geoserver web interface. Note that a similar trick with the Update Transaction demo works perfectly.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

You have told GeoServer that the feature you are adding is in EPSG:4326 (that's `srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326"`) but your coordinates are

```
494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
```

which are clearly not in latitude and longitude degrees. So GeoServer has added them but they are a **long** way away from Tasmania so you can't see them, unless you zoom out a lot and then they will be too small to see.

So you either need to use the correct projection information for your geometry (I can't be sure but maybe EPSG:3758 Web Mercator?) or provide the coordinates in latitude/longitude format.

You might also want to raise a bug on the [GeoServer Jira](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary) about this error.

Comment: Thanks iant, I got your point, but I'm presently busy elsewhere. As soon as I re-check the code with your suggestion I'll close the question and raise the bug with a solution. Thank you.